# ZeroMQ server client start sequence

Tags: c++11, zeromq

Facing a issue if the client is started before server

Specs : ubuntu 16.04 with c++11,libzmq : 4.2.3

problem : sample codes

server.cpp

```
int main()
{
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t requester(context,ZMQ_ROUTER);
.
//code to get address
.    
requester.bind(address);

while(true)
{
zmq::message_t message;
requester.recv(&message);
.
//remaining code
.
}
return 0;
}
```

client.cpp

```
int main()
{
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t requester(context,ZMQ_DEALER);
.
//code to get address
.
requester.connect(address);
zmq::message_t message;
.
//populate the message to send
.

requester.send(message);
return 0;
}
```

I know that in zmq i can start client even if the server is not running,but my client application has to include a safety check which requires the server to be started.Is there any way i can achieve by making connect fail or someother workaround.Timeout options doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Make the send non blocking, if there there is no server(s) available the send will fail and set an errno

http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-send

```
ZMQ_DONTWAIT
For socket types (DEALER, PUSH) that block when there are no available peers 
(or all peers have full high-water mark), specifies that the operation should 
be performed in non-blocking mode. If the message cannot be queued on the 
socket, the zmq_send() function shall fail with errno set to EAGAIN.
```

Comment: Thnaks i will try it